# Does Apple watch calories burned use weight in health settings?

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

Does the apple watch use weight value in health setting when calculating the total calories burned for the day so far?  If not where does it look at weight somewhere else or even at all?

[image]

Comment: @Thinkr Please don't write comments like "You clearly haven't understood what you're talking about here", this is rather aggressive and totally unnecessary (and, in the specific case, rather ironic if I compare your (now deleted) comments with the answer by Allan).

Answer (score 1):

According to [MacObserver](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/how-apple-fitness-calculate-calories/), the Health App will calculate (estimate) the number of calories burned by evaluating your BMR and AMR; your resting metabolic rate and your active metabolic rate, respectively.

Both of these equations rely on weight.

- [BMR Formula](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/health/bmr-formula.php), Also see [NIH.gov](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK278991/table/diet-treatment-obes.table12est/).  It’s not a complex formula, but there are different values depending on your sex.  Here’s the Harris-Benedict formula.  There’s also the more modern [Mifflin - St Jeor Equation](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article-abstract/51/2/241/4695104?redirectedFrom=PDF&login=false)

  [image]
- [Active Metabolic Rate](https://www.verywellfit.com/how-many-calories-do-i-need-each-day-2506873).  This is much easier to calculate:  it’s your BMR multiplied by an activity coefficient (i.e. walking = X).  The health app will track your activities (steps taken, resting, running, etc.) and, input the values and estimate the number of calories you burned.

So, the short answer is, yes, your weight is a factor in determining calories burned.

Comment: Does this mean that heart rate plays no part in the calculation? Or is it factored into the "activity coefficient"? You're making it sound like the type of activity (which I don't always bother to specify) is the key part of the equation...

Comment: @Christoph - I made no such implication.  I touched on AMR for reference only - the question was about whether or not *weight* was factor in the calculation.

Comment: So, do you know whether heart rate is part of the calculation?

Comment: @Christoph, Apple doesn’t disclose their algorithm, but it would make sense to monitor/measure [heart rate during exercise to properly estimate the calories burned](https://www.livestrong.com/article/39443-heart-rate-vs.-calories-burned/).